# Scroll to specific place on the page does not work browser Edge

Tags: javascript, html

I can't understand why this function doesn't work properly on Edge.

```
function contactos(thi) 
{
    var contactos = document.getElementById('contactos');
    window.scrollTo(0, contactos.offsetTop - 160 );

}
```

And this is the html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="contactos(this)">Contatos</a>
```

Comment: what to you mean by *Does not work properly* ?

Comment: I load the link and the page does not move while in the chrome and safari I load the link and it goes to the location of the page defined

Comment: do you get any error in the js console ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) on Edge and it works as expected.

The only thing that comes to mind is, maybe `contactos` doesn't exist or it doesn't have an `offsetTop` property. To debug it:

1. Go to Edge
2. Open [developer tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide) (press F12)
3. In the Console tab, write `document.getElementById('contactos')`
4. If it prints something other that `undefined`, it exists.
5. Write `document.getElementById('contactos').offsetTop`
6. If it prints something other that `undefined`, it exists.

If you successfully reach the last point, it's because there is an problem somewhere else in the code. You might have to debug further.

**Edit**: You don't have an element with an id "contactos". You can do one of three things:

1. Since you're passing this to your function (`function contactos(element)`), you can just `window.scrollTo(0, element.offsetTop - 160 );`
2. Or, you first set `var contactos = element`, and keep the rest.
3. Or, better, set an id in the html element, like so: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="contactos" onclick="contactos(this)">Contatos</a>`

Here's a snippet. Try making it a button.

```js
function contactos(element) 
{
    window.scrollTo(0, element.offsetTop + 160);    
}
```

```html
<button onclick="contactos(this)">Contactos</button>

<!-- gibberish -->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<p>Text added just to see movement</p>
```

Comment: erro: "Unable to get property 'offsetTop' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: @TâniaDias That means, you can't get a property of something that doesn't exists. You don't have an element with an id "contactos".

Comment: In html I have this:
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="contactos(this)">Contatos</a>

Comment: @TâniaDias Add it to your question

Comment: Does not work the id has to be placed where I want the scroll page already to try the various options and it does not work.

Comment: @TâniaDias Have you tried making it a button? There's no reason it shouldn't work. Test the snippet, it works perfectly fine in Chrome and Edge.